# URL data printing trouble

Tags: java, user-interface, url

I am reading from a URL = https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt

I am trying to print out the top 3 countries but whenever I try it gives
me the total number of countries instead. Would a subString or Trim method work here? Just need a hint into the write direction. Thanks

```
    class ButtonTotalListener implements ActionListener
        {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {                 
           if(event.getSource()==printButton){
           String line = "";
           try{
            String address = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2151.txt";
            URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
            while(in.hasNextLine()){
            line = in.nextLine();
            String [] lineContent = line.split("\\s{2,}");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineContent));
            countries.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            countries.setText(lineContent[2]);
            }
            } 
              catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                  countries.setText("Country Not Found!");
              } 
              catch (IOException ex) {}
     }
```

Comment: Use a variable to keep count of how many iterations your while loop has made and change the while loop to the following `int count = 0; while(count < 3 && in.hasNextLine()) { ...; count += 1; }`. Don't forget to `close()` the `Scanner` after you're done with it. I would also `printStackTrace()`s of the exceptions your encounter, this will be vary helpful if you run into errors while developing.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over all countries in in.hasNextLine()

You should introduce a counter variable and insert a break; after your limit was reached, or change the loop condition.

Additionally check which column you want to return. It seems you return the number from thrid column (which is [2]), but if you want to use the country name you need [1] for 2nd column (array index is 0-based).

As a third, what do you do with countries? You set the text, but for each loop iteration, you overwrite the former countries text (countries is the same variable, in each iteration)

Comment: I have the countries attached to a button that when pressed prints the top three countries from the URL. I just did not attach the GUI code for that. I appreciate your help, my professor has not emailed me back for help in three days.